# how to print the last record of each admission number in sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having a database where i have stored fees collected from several students.

I am having column like:-

```
admno      name           class         section       tuitionfee
SJS001    Arjun        nursery              a          3000
SJS002    akash        nursery              a          2000
SJS001    arjun        nursery              a          1000
SJS005    baldev       class-II             b          5000
```

There may be a same admission number who might have paid several times his tuition fees.
Now i want only to print the last value of all the entered admission number how can i do this.

Comment: Do you have an id column in the table?

Comment: Put a column FeeSubmittedData. Using this column you can either use top 1 order by FeeSubmittedData DESC, or use CROSS JOIN to get the last fee submitted on the max(FeeSubmittedData).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print the last admission, you need to add column `admissionDate`. Then you can do something like this:

```sql
SELECT TOP(1) admno,name,class,section,tuitionfee, ADMISSIONDATE
FROM table_name
Where admno = 'SJS001'
Order by ADMISSIONDATE desc
```

This is Sql Server specific syntax. There are other ways to achieve this result, Like using `MAX(ADMISSIONDATE)` in subquery.

```sql
select * 
from a t1 
where 
    t1.admno = 'SJS001' And 
    ADMISSIONDATE = (select max(ADMISSIONDATE) from a t2 where t1.admno = t2.admno)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an Id column in your db to order entries by, then

In SQL:

```
SELECT * from YOUR_TABLE
where id in 
(select max(id)
from YOUR_TABLE
group by admno)
```

In Linq:

```
var ids = YOUR_TABLE.GroupBy(y => y.admno).Select(y => y.Max(z => z.Id));
var result = YOURT_TABLE.Join(ids, x => x.Id, y => y, (x,y) => x);
```